# Curved labels on circular diagram (D3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

So, I'm basically trying to make a multilevel circular partition (aka sunburst diagram) with D3.js (v4) and a JSON data.

I placed some labels, which must have different angles depending of their levels (circles) on the partition :
- Level < 3 must be curved and "follow" the arc radius.
- level == 3 must be straight and perpendicular of the arc radius.

I didn't use textPath tags, because I'm not really experienced in SVG and it looks overly complicated to me, and I don't really know how to use it.

here's my code (without the JSON but this is a really classical one, I can add a part of it if it is needed):

```
var width = 800;
var height = 800;
var radius = 400;
var formatNumber = d3.format(",d");
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);
var y = d3.scaleSqrt().range([0, radius]);

var arc = d3.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x0))); })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x1))); })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return setRadius("inner", d.data.level); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return setRadius("outer", d.data.level); });

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + (height/2) + ")");

var hierarchy = d3.hierarchy(dataset)
    .sum(function(d) { return d.size; });

var partition = d3.partition();

svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(partition(hierarchy).descendants())
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("id", function(d, i){ return "path" + i; })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return (d.data.color) ? d.data.color : 'black'; });

svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(partition(hierarchy).descendants())
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d){ return setLabelPosition(d); })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", "18px")
    .attr("fill", function(d){ return d.data.textcolor; })
    .text(function(d){ if(parseInt(d.data.level) > 0 && parseInt(d.data.level) < 4){ return (d.data.name).toUpperCase(); }});

d3.select(self.frameElement)
    .style("height", height + "px");

function setRadius(side, level){
    var result = 0;
    var innerValues = [0, 120, 180, 240, 365];
    var outerValues = [0, 180, 240, 365, 400];
    if(!side){
        throw error;
    }
    if(side === "inner"){
        result = innerValues[level];
    }
    if(side === "outer"){
        result = outerValues[level];
    }
    return result;
};

function setLabelPosition(d){
    var result = '';
    var angle = 0;
    var centroid = arc.centroid(d);
    if(parseInt(d.data.level) === 3){
        angle = (180/Math.PI * (arc.startAngle()(d) + arc.endAngle()(d))/2 - 90);
        if(angle > 90){
            angle = angle - 180;
        }
        result = "translate(" + centroid + ")rotate(" + angle + ")";
    } else {
        angle = (180/Math.PI * (arc.startAngle()(d) + arc.endAngle()(d))/2);
        result = "translate(" + centroid + ")rotate(" + angle + ")";
    }
    return result;
};
```

And the result :
[image: sunburst diagram]
My problem is, how to curve these level 1 & 2 labels (like the one which have a red border), but keep my lvl 3 labels as they currently are.

It's really a pain in the head, and I did many search (on Google and SO) but I didn't find any satisfying answer.
A solution without using a textPath will be awesome if possible, but any advice is welcome.

Many thanks guys and sorry for my English (as you can probably see it's not my birth language).

PS : This is D3.js v4.

Comment: I think the answer is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169874/d3-donut-chart-with-curved-labels